# Pre-checking security at BLR ... typical, and what to do in general?

Tags: airport-security, emirates, bangalore

I flew BLR to DXB a couple of weeks ago on Emirates. I was taken aback to discover that there was a security check to get into the airport *at all*, where the requirements were ID and Boarding Pass. Well, there I was with plenty of ID, and an Emirates phone app that reported that I needed to check in, in person, inside the airport, to receive a boarding pass.

I was relieved to discover that the uniformed person at the head of the line would accept any evidence of my identity associated with the flight in the Emirates app, and I found some for him in real time.

Did I miss a memo? Should I have somehow known to print something?

Comment: I have heard about other 'outside the airport' checks, often installed at short notice after problems at the airport, and all of them did accept proof of a ticket and an ID as needed for that flight. (So in some cases no ID at all.)

Comment: i don't have a full answer for you, but: this kind of pre-airport-entry check is extremely common (universal?) in Indian airports, and I never fully understood exactly what documents they expect you to have, but in practice it seems to be fine to show up with a foreign passport plus anything that looks even vaguely like evidence of a flight to catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Airport entry checks are in my experience near-universal in Indian airports.  Back in the 2000s, they used to insist on a hard copy printout of your flight itinerary, so I've made it a habit to always bring one along, but I gather showing a ticket on your phone is fine these days.

As far as I can tell, all they do is check that you have ID (for foreign nationals, this has to be a passport, even for domestic flights) and that you have something vaguely ticket-like with today's date and a name that matches your ID.  The validity of the ticket/PNR is *not* checked, and you are not required to present a boarding pass, since this check is before checking in.